# WooCommerce Search Form From Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, forms, search, woocommerce

I am using the following to place a search form in a slider revolution hero slide. However it searches the entire site. I would like it to only search woocommerce products. Any ideas what I need to change to make that work?

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="revtp-searchform" action="http://mywebsiteURL.com/"/>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using [codex: pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and [developer: pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_woocommerce_product' );

function search_woocommerce_product( $query ) {
  if( ! is_admin() && is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
  }
}
```

You can add further condition to this hook function like include in particular page only [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

Or with certain short code like this

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
$patternToken = 'masterslider';

if (preg_match_all('/' . $pattern . '/s', get_the_content(), $matches) &&
array_key_exists(2, $matches) && 
in_array($patternToken, $matches[2])) {
//Your code logic
}
```